# Why am I getting duplicates when combining multiple ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

Why I am getting duplicate entries in my `ArrayList<String[]>`?

- allStepsJSONStringArray contains an array of single strings in the format of JSON
- I loop through and pass each JSON string to a function that writes it to a temporary internal file
- I read the file
- Then pass it to `getStepsArray()` which breaks down the JSON string and puts each entry into a `String[]`

**Loop to add to master ArrayList - allStepsArray**

```
for (int i = 0; i < allStepsJSONStringArray.size(); i++) {
    writer.writeToInternal(allStepsJSONStringArray.get(i));
    reader.readFromInternal(writer.filename); 
    stepsArray = reader.getStepsArray();
    for (int s = 0; s < stepsArray.size(); s++) {
        allStepsArray.add(stepsArray.get(s));
    }
}
```

**getStepsArray()**

```
public ArrayList<String[]> getStepsArray() {
    try {
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("steps");
        String stepOrder = null;
        String stepName = null;
        String stepType = null;
        String stepId = null;
        String checklistId = null;
        String checklistName = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            stepOrder = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("order");
            stepName = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
            stepType = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("type");
            stepId = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
            checklistId = jObject.getString("checklistId");
            checklistName = jObject.getString("checklistName");
            stepsArray.add(new String[] {stepOrder, stepName, stepType, stepId, checklistName, checklistId});
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return stepsArray;
}
```

Comment: Because you don't seem to ever reset `stepsArray`. The second time you add elements to it, the previous elements will still be there and will get added to `allStepsArray` again.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You are correct! If you want some points, create an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word for word:

Because you don't seem to ever reset `stepsArray`. The second time you add elements to it, the previous elements will still be there and will get added to `allStepsArray` again.

Comment: @TheNomad Don't worry about it, as long as you've solved your issue.